# Present EditView of Contacts in ContactsUI

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

I have a TableView that present a contact. 
When I click the cell i would like to do straight to Editable view, instead of going to the CNContactViewController and press "edit Button".
Now i have the following :

[firstview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H72G.png)

[secondview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJmue.png)

I would like to skip the second step. Is that possible?

the code I'm using is the same from apple's:

```
let contacts = try contactStore.unifiedContactWithIdentifier
        (contactIdentifier!, keysToFetch: toFetch)
    let controller = CNContactViewController(forContact: contacts)
        controller.contactStore = contactStore
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.editing = true

        navigationController?
            .pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        print(controller.editButtonItem())

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

EDIT: More or less, to illustrate, what Im trying to do, is the same as WhatsApp has in their App!, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this approach ?

```
let toFetch = [CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]

let contacts = try contactStore.unifiedContactWithIdentifier
        (contactIdentifier!, keysToFetch: toFetch)

let contactsViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contacts)
contactsViewController.delegate = self
contactsViewController.title = "Edit contact"
contactsViewController.contactStore = contactStore

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactsViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for the answer! but this function "CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contacts)" brings the view I want, except is to create a new contact, not to edit one that exists already.

Comment: If you pass in an existing contact for the newContact parameter it would be to edit that particular contact. This was the behaviour I experienced with my testing

Comment: but then when the user finishes editing and click "save", wouldn't duplicate that contact?

Comment: I tested with a very limited amount of contacts so that I could identify duplicates easily but I could not seem to see any contacts being duplicated. Did you notice anything like that ?. I wonder if there is any other solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi Jani! It actually worked! Thank you very much!! The only thing I have to set now is how to go back.

Comment: Glad it worked. Do you mean to go back when you press cancel ?

Comment: yeah, Implementing the exactly way you wrote above, when i go to the edit view, I can't go back (press cancel), the only way to exit the view is by pressing "done". i have to find a way to go around this issue, but once again thank you!!

Comment: Your delegate method func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWithContact contact: CNContact?). Should be called when you tap the cancel button. Simply pop the view controller from the navigationController like self.navigationController?.popViewController(true)

Comment: It's working perfectly with ContactUI framework. Is it possible to do this with AddressBookUI framework also?